# How to check whether array is empty or not in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs,I am fetching data using axios, I just want to check before map/loop that whether whether array is empty or not , means if code/loop should work if i have data in array (students.data),How can i do this ? Here is my current code

```
const [students,setStudents] = useState({
  data: '',
  loading: true
})
const [name,setName] = useState('');
const handleClick2 = async() => {
    $("#mostviews").hide();
        const response = await axios.get(`https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/${spath}`)
     setStudents({
        data: response.data,
        loading: false
    })
}

{students.data.map((caseStudy ) => (
<a>{caseStudy.title}</a>
))}
```

In Network tab i am getting data like following way

```
0   Object { id: "66", cat_name: "pined", title: "Game Engine", … }
1   Object { id: "40", cat_name: "pined", title: "Alpha Release Time !", … }
```

Comment: the result in console is in array or objects are in an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for your requirement and your current code is to use **&&** operator. Check the following.

```
 {students.data?.length > 0 &&
     students.data.map((caseStudy) => (
      <a>{caseStudy.title}</a>
  ))}
```

Comment: sorry but its not working, nothing showing in page

Comment: Yes. It doesn't show anything if your students array has no value. Please make sure that your students array have value or not.

Comment: array contaning values , not empty but if i use "length" then nothing displaying, i updated my question ( added more code)

Comment: could you write your console.log for that array(students.data) ?

Comment: i just posted my data which i am getting in network tab(console) , kindly check

Comment: Thz for your update. Let me ask another question. Without that condition, are you sure that caseStudy.title display well ?

Comment: your code is working but data updated after refresh page,How can i fix this ?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. When you refresh the page , your students data will get again from your api. Isn't it normal?

Comment: By the way, you can also use useEffect hook for that and if my previous answer is correct, please kindly marked this answer as correct answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: can you tell me how can i use "useeffect" in this module ?

Comment: Before fixing that, i need more information to solve it. You need to tell me the whole problem and your requirement first. The best way is you should create another question to share your problem more detail. And mention me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {students && students.length ?
     students.data.map((caseStudy) => (
      <a>{caseStudy.title}</a>
  )) : ""}
```

Comment: its not working, data is not displaying

Comment: see this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-playground-practice-wrksbs?file=App.js,index.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code like this, you are using wrong brackets `()` instead of `{}`, and if there only one line you can just skip it by writing it in single line as we do in arrow functions usually:

```
const [students,setStudents] = useState({
  data: [], //change string to array
  loading: true
})
const [name,setName] = useState('');
const handleClick2 = async() => {
    let arr = []
    $("#mostviews").hide();
        const response = await axios.get(`https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/${spath}`)
        for (const key in response.data) { //if assuming you are getting objects in object instead of obj in array
            arr.push(response.data[key])
        }
     setStudents({
        data: arr,
        loading: false
    })
}

{students.length > 0 && students.data.map((caseStudy ) => {
    return <a>{caseStudy.title}</a>
})}
```

or if you want to render something when there is no data in array then use:
`condition ? renderThis : OrThis`

Comment: We need to see more code, like where you are getting data in your array.

Comment: Also you are enclosing it in `( )` instead of `{ }`

Comment: can you update your answer so i can check and implement at my side

Comment: still not displaying anything , actually "students.length" not working in my side (showing nothing)

Comment: change `data: ""` to `data: []` as well and try

Comment: sorry but still not working i updated my question,I posted which i am getting in network tab (json data) , still i am getting nothing with "{students.length}"

Comment: check the type of `response.data` its an array or an object, i updated my answer in case of you object.

Comment: its working but correct(updated) data is displaying after refresh page, should i  use "useeffect" ? or something other ? kindly update

Comment: your page is getting refreshing on click event? or what?

Comment: data is displaying fine but whenever i click on any blog then "old data"( not updated) displaying

Comment: looks like we need more code specifically the data you are fetching, Like you dont have any predefined data so it should't beahve like this.